# qml animation unexpected behavior

Tags: animation, qml, behavior

Why rectangle with "Behavior on x" animation moves to left side, while without animation holding its position( as expected ).

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 800
height: 600

Rectangle
{
 id: rect
 x: 300
 y: 0
 width: 100
 height:100
 color: "red"
 MouseArea {
     anchors.fill: parent
     onClicked: {
         rect.x+=50
         rect.x-=50
     }
 }
 Behavior on x { NumberAnimation {duration: 400} }
}}
```

And how to create animation to every x property changing?

Answer (score 0):

The first `rect.x+=50` initiates the `NumberAnimation`. But before it gets a chance to animate the property change, you initiate another `NumberAnimation` with `rect.y-=50`, cancelling the first animation.

> And how to create animation to every x property changing?

Don't immediately change the x coordinate after you've initially changed it. If you tell us what you're trying to do in terms of the end result, we might be able to help you further.